# Legend labeling issue with ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

This is sort of a nitpicky issue but I'm having trouble displaying the color of a line in the legend for the graph.  In the box next to "Sabry Lee" the color should be blue, but it's blank, for some reason.

Here's the data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(STRING = c("1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC"), time = structure(c(13239, 13422, 
13483, 13545, 13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 
13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 
14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 
14335), class = "Date"), ee_qty = c(NA, 2302, 3434, 1800, 2766, 
4408, 6314, 2860, 2476, 1572, 4950, 1812, 14100, 7591, NA, NA, 
11823, NA, NA, 11829, 3836, 5378, 4804, 4356, 3655, 5955, 1345, 
4717, 8854, 11494), ee_amt = c(NA, 33815.88, 60107.4, 66279.2, 
66814.46, 129042.18, 151649.49, 58576.2, 61984.58, 61782, 102648.16, 
67844.4, 362371.82, 159274.66, NA, NA, 285847.62, NA, NA, 258045.26, 
82306.74, 119702.9, 113514.6, 118765.82, 86298.66, 155659.83, 
40246.14, 134675.59, 236084.63, 256467.56), elite_qty = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1281, 3037, 2141, 1764, 1661, 
1838, 2780, 2627, 2498, 3137, 2238, 2470, 1107, 1886, 844, 798, 
NA, 1588, 1919, 2603), elite_amt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 34956.08, 48618.37, 58880.59, 49141.23, 49067.42, 
40105.91, 89717.69, 78612.5, 40608.3599999999, 65893.38, 33706.66, 
77191.76, 45096.9, 55742.83, 29993.7600000000, 27171.22, NA, 
1427.23, 2466.64, 54500.19), Sabry_Qty = c(596, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Sabry_amt = c(17761.06, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), depo_qty = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
902, 319, 883, 597, 854, 710, 911, 573, 447, 857, 795, 997, 822
), depo_amt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31011.68, 13556.65, 32134.72, 23106.94, 36681.95, 
30220.74, 38051.93, 24941.85, 19337.46, 31360.4, 30182.18, 41363.71, 
34419.34), tyc_qty = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 58, 116, 136), tyc_amt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3103.73, 7538.71, 7497.34), string2 = c("1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", 
"1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC", "1A AUTO INC")), .Names = c("STRING", 
"time", "ee_qty", "ee_amt", "elite_qty", "elite_amt", "Sabry_Qty", 
"Sabry_amt", "depo_qty", "depo_amt", "tyc_qty", "tyc_amt", "string2"
), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code to produce the plot:

```
p = ggplot(df2)
p = p + 
    geom_line(aes(time, ee_amt, colour="ee_amt"), size = 2) + 
    geom_point(aes(time, ee_amt, colour="ee_amt"), size = 2) + 
    geom_line(aes(time, elite_amt, colour="elite_amt"), size = 2) + 
    geom_point(aes(time, elite_amt, colour="elite_amt"), size = 2) +
    geom_line(aes(time, Sabry_amt, colour="Sabry_amt"), size = 2) + 
    geom_point(aes(time, Sabry_amt, colour="Sabry_amt"), size = 2) +
    geom_line(aes(time, depo_amt, colour="depo_amt"), size = 2) + 
    geom_point(aes(time, depo_amt, colour="depo_amt"), size = 2) +
    geom_line(aes(time, tyc_amt, colour="tyc_amt"), size = 2) + 
    geom_point(aes(time, tyc_amt, colour="tyc_amt"), size = 2) +
    ylab("Revenue (Dollars)") + 
    xlab("Time") + 
    labs(colour = "") + 
    opts(legend.position="right") + 
    opts(title = "Stuff") +
    scale_color_manual(name ="", 
                       values = c("red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"),                 
                       breaks=c("ee_amt", "elite_amt", "Sabry_Amt", "depo_amt", "tyc_amt"), 
                       labels=c("Eagle Eyes", "E-lite", "Sabry Lee", "Depo", "TYC"))
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you haven't `melt`ed your data frame first?

Comment: I'm a noob to R.  What does "melt" mean?

Comment: Ok...your immediate problem is that you wrote "Sabry_Amt" instead of "Sabry_amt" in the scale call.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it the wrong way. First `melt` your data, and then use it to let `ggplot` do the work for you so you don't have to put 5 calls to `geom_line` and `geom_point`. And it's usually safer to get the breaks from levels, much less typing and much less error prone.

```
library(reshape2)

df2M <- melt(df2, measure.vars = c("ee_amt", "elite_amt", "Sabry_amt", "depo_amt", "tyc_amt"))

ggplot(df2M, aes(time, value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
 labs(colour = "", x = "Time", y = "Revenue (Dollars)") + 
 opts(legend.position="right", title = "Stuff") +
  scale_color_manual(name ="", values = c("red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"), 
                     breaks= levels(df2M$variable), 
                     labels=c("Eagle Eyes", "E-lite", "Sabry Lee", "Depo", "TYC"))
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. The answer I was in the midst of writing was also going to point out that the `xlab` and `ylab` can both be set in `labs`, and the two `opts` calls can be combined.

Comment: Right, I was typing out a similar solution.

Comment: @joran I udpated the answer to include the merge of calls.

Comment: Oh I get it, you're transposing the data to long format, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what melt means.